# Add space before text in react js component

Tags: html, reactjs

I have this component `<TEXT>{' '} (CAR)</TEXT>`. I try to add an empty space before `(CAR)` using `{' '}`, but when the text is rendered the space is gone. 
 Why the space is not added and how to add it?

Comment: What makes you think it's not there? Have you a more complete example?

Comment: try this &nbsp;

Answer (score 4):

You can use `&nbsp;` to create space

```
<TEXT>&nbsp;&nbsp;(CAR)</TEXT>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's just the way HTML renders whitespace as part of the spec.

From [MDN: How whitespace is handled by HTML, CSS, and in the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace#html_largely_ignores_whitespace):

> In the case of HTML, whitespace is largely ignored — whitespace in between words is treated as a single character, and whitespace at the start and end of elements and outside elements is ignored.

If you need visual negative space, you can use a style with [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) or [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).